# SQL Server Geometry draw rectangle around a line

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I am VERY new to spatial data queries, so please bear with me. 
I have a LineString (geometry) in SQL Server and need to "draw" a rectangle around it, based on padding for the Width and the Height, using the existing line.
Is there a direct way to do so using the Spatial API in SQL Server?

Comment: STEnvelope is what you are looking for.

Comment: You would think, but this is now what I need. STEnvelope creates a vertical rectangle (the long sided is at 90 degrees to the X axis) that includes the line. What I need is to create a rectangle (polygon) that keeps the direction/angle of the original line. In other words, the new lines need to be at a 90 degree angle with the existing line (or parallel).

Comment: I really need to pad the line in the shape of a rectangle. I also need to be able to specify padding for the longer and shorter side. is there a method that can do that?